# Best Way to initialize a instance variable in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having trouble initializing instance variables in Rails, need to use a variable in different methods, but this needs to be initialized beforehand, eg:

```rb
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base    
  @test = 1

  def testing
    @test+1
  end    
end

t = Test.new
t.testing
```

I get the follow error:

```
test.rb:4:in `testar': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from test.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

Is there a more elegant way to initialize a variable without using the `after_initialize`?:

Comment: What's wrong with the constructor (`initialize`, invoked on `new`)?

Comment: `after_initialize` is the way to go

Comment: @D-side as it is from AR::Base, you don't want to override initialize as it can break AR..

Comment: @Doon got it. And AR provides a replacement the author wants to avoid. Huh.

Comment: @D-side yes there is a callback that AR provides after it runs initialize.  that OP is looking to avoid

Comment: Be careful that the first `@test = 1` has `self` pointing to your class, not to your instance.

Comment: removed attr_accessor_with_default comments as it looks like they deprecated it (Ive not used it in a really long time, lol)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So `after_initialize` seems to be really the best solution.

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_initialize do
    @test = 1
  end

  def testing
    @test+=1
  end
end
```

Comment: issue is you dont update @test in your testing method

Comment: This should be `@test += 1` if you actually want to modify it.

Answer (score 2):

If you really dont want to use `after_initialize`, create the variable on the fly:

```
attr_writer :test

def testing
  self.test += 1
end

def test
  @test ||= 0
end
```

Comment: I need use @test in several places.

Comment: It's best to use the accessor method than to lean directly on `@`-style instance variables when writing model code.

Comment: @apneadiving Exactly as you have here with the lazy initializer `||=`. Once you have that, the `@test` variable should not be used directly is all I'm saying.

Comment: @tadman actually I hesitated but didnt take the time to check :)

Answer (score 1):

What you've defined in your code is a `@test` class instance variables, and you probably wanted just an instance variable.
Using `after_initialize` is overkill here, you can do something like:

```
  def test
    @test ||= 1
  end
```

Comment: yeah maybe you meant `attr_writer`